# How is this custom tag configured?

Tags: angularjs, configure, custom-tag

I'm using this library https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat

So to create a list of nodes this syntax is used :

```
<li frang-tree-repeat="node in treeData>
```

`frang-tree-repeat` is a custom tag and so it has to be configured somewhere within the library ?

Searching the src of https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat I do not see any references to  frang-tree-repeat so how is this tag configured or in other words how is frang-tree-repeat interpreted ?

Comment: It's here https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat/blob/master/app/js/directives.js#L18 Remember to normalize directive names: frangTreeRepeat.

Comment: @dfsq so directive frangTreeRepeat is read as frang-Tree-Repeat on angular view page? Is this insertion of '-' to read a directive from view page an angularjs standard ?

Comment: Read my answer, I explained it why this normalization is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular normalizes directive (both attribute and tag) names from kebab-case to camelCase. This is necessary since names of HTML tags and attributes are better written in kebab-case (because names are not case sensitive in HTML) while in Javascript kebab-case names would not be valid identifiers and could not be used for directives names (well, they *could*, but it would require additional wrapping into quotes).

That's the reason why you have to preform normalization from HTML notation to JS. Angular has [$normalize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) service which is used for this. So it means, that if in HTML you have `frang-tree-repeat` it will be translated to `frangTreeRepeat` in Javascript.

In your case, your directive is found here: https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat/blob/master/app/js/directives.js#L18

Answer (score 0):

`frang-tree-repeat` is a custom **[directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)** which is defined in a **module** `app.directives` in *angular-treeRepeat*. As @dfsq pointed out, its implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/tchatel/angular-treeRepeat/blob/master/app/js/directives.js#L18).

Note that it requires `frangtree`in its definition `require: ^frangTree`:

> When a *directive* uses this option, `$compile` will throw an error unless the specified *controller* is found. The `^` prefix means that this *directive* searches for the *controller* on its parents (without the `^` prefix, the *directive* would look for the *controller* on just its own element).